# Is it correct to say 'it doesn't matter anything'?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm well aware that one would usually say 'it doesn't matter'. But considering that there is such an expression as 'what does it matter', can we say 'it doesn't matter anything'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding *"at all"* to give *"it doesn't matter at all"* is one way of emphasing the unimportance. Adding *"anything"*, as suggested in the question, is not correct.

I have heard some people use the (mild profanity) *"it doesn't matter a damm"* for the same effect. I would not use it. (UK English)

Comment: Or "It doesn't matter *a bit*", or *the least bit*.

Comment: Or it doesn't matter a jot.